# OpenSuse - Can't install Rails: File not found on medium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opensuse

I'm trying to set up a Ruby on Rails environment within OpenSuse, but I've encountered a problem. When running `sudo zypper install rubygem-railties-3_2` all I get is `File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Banshee/12.1/'`. So something seems to be wrong at their side.

Is there anyone who as a workaround for, or more info about, this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When running the command `$ sudo zypper up` I was receiving a similar error:

> File ... not found on medium http:// ...

Detailed error:

> File './x86_64/libxkbcommon0-0.7.2-48.2.x86_64.rpm' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/KDE:/Qt5/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/'

The solution which worked for me was to run `$ sudo zypper ref` **before** running `$ sudo zypper up`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have setup an additional repository for Banshee for a very old opensuse version. Opensuse only keeps its repositories alive for the last two two releases to the current release. For this reason, you get this error. You can disable or remove the repositorium to resolve the error.

In order to install packages that are not part of the currently configured repositories, it is the easiest to use the one-click install available at https://software.opensuse.org/search .